# To what extent is margins different from lincom/nlcom (in Stata)?

Tags: regression, stata, marginal-effects

What exactly is the difference between `margins` and `lincom` in Stata? How can I adjust my manual formula in `nlcom` to match the result of `margins`? Thank you

```
* load data
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork

* set panel structure
xtset idcode year

* fixed effects regression 
xtreg ln_wage c.wks_ue##c.wks_ue union age, fe coeflegend
margins, dydx(wks_ue)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      wks_ue |    -.00594   .0009744    -6.10   0.000    -.0078497   -.0040303
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

* check with lincom/nlcom
lincom _b[wks_ue] + 2*_b[c.wks_ue#c.wks_ue]
nlcom _b[wks_ue] + 2*_b[c.wks_ue#c.wks_ue]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _nl_1 |  -.0062406   .0010319    -6.05   0.000    -.0082632   -.0042181
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Indeed, I'm rather interested in the one line of `lincom` that makes results equivalent to `margins`. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the mean value of `wks_ue`. Get it from the estimated sample, save it as a local and include it in `lincom`. Coefficient and standard error will be the same. `lincom` uses a t-distribution and `margins` uses a z-distribution.

```
* load data
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork

* set panel structure
xtset idcode year

* fixed effects regression 
xtreg ln_wage c.wks_ue##c.wks_ue union age, fe coeflegend
margins, dydx(wks_ue)

qui sum wks_ue if e(sample)
local wks_ue_mean = r(mean)

lincom wks_ue + 2*c.wks_ue#c.wks_ue*`wks_ue_mean'
```

[image]